# is there easier way to create attached drawings in PPT or Visio?

Tags: 3d, powerpoint

I'd like to create a fancy drawing like

[image: my favourite sample]

I tried to create similar one using PPT (3D format), but it's so painful.

So, is there any tools or plugins that makes it easier?

Comment: This site is for programming problems. Please post your question at answers.microsoft.com or super User.

Comment: Thank you, John!